# redirect automatic page that serves custom posttype content

Tags: custom-post-types, redirect, page-template, htaccess, template-hierarchy

I registered `blog` as a custom post type. This content is queried on the page `page-actueel-blog`. But `mydomain.com/blog` also serves content (by default titles are queried).

I don't want visitors to see this page `/blog` since this is not designed / styled. **Can I let WordPress redirect `/blog` to `page-actueel-blog`** or should I do this in the .htaccess file?

Should I do this with htaccess, what is the proper redirect (since `/blog` and `page-actueel-blog` might both match *blog*)

Comment: But this /blog/ will be still visible in single post page (when you go to single blog post, it will have /blog/ in url...)

Comment: That is right.. they may visit mydomain.com/blog/blogpost. But I want mydomain.com/blog to redirect to mydomain.com/actueel-blog

Comment: It doesn’t make much sense. You’re breaking url structure logic this way...

Comment: I know it doesn't make much sense. This is not the point. I am looking for a way to redirect.

Comment: If you want to do it with htaccess, then it has nothing to do with WP and is off-topic here. If you want to solve it correctly, you’ll have to explain what exactly are you trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own question without breaking the url structure logic, as Krzysiek Dróżdż (thanks!) suggested.

I changed the page named `/page-actueel-blog` to the custom-post-type 'archive' template. Pretty obvious, but I thought archive was something else entirely.

For whoever may have the same doubts: the archive template is the level up from domain.com/blogpost (single-mycustomposttypename.php); a collection page of all posts. I named it `archive-mycustomposttypename.php`.